# Как добавить картинку в DatagridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть колонка, в которой необходимо отображать картинки товаров. Как добавить в ячейку колонки DatagridView нужную картинку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `DataGridView` есть стандартный тип колонки для картинок - [`DataGridViewImageColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn(v=vs.110).aspx), которую можно прибайндить к колонке или свойству типа `System.Drawing.Image` из источника данных.

Колонку можно добавить или прямо в дизайнере, или кодом:

```
var imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imageColumn);
```

Comment: Это понятно. Создан класс с методом                                           public Bitmap LoadBitmap(string fileName)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileName) == false) //Если сам файл отсутствует
            {
              return null;
            }

            using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(fileName), 200, 200 )) // Добать size
            {
                return new Bitmap(bm);
            }
        }

Comment: Непосредственно добавление  Class1 cl = new Class1();

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(                                     cl.LoadBitmap(strPathFoto))

Comment: @АлександрПузанов если у вас есть какие-то уточнения или код - отредактируйте сам вопрос. а то не совсем понятно что же именно у вас не получается